# How do I disable Chrome's two-finger back/forward on specific website

Tags: safari, google-chrome

How can I disable two fingers back/forward on a specific website?
I want to disable that feature in all trading sites, e.g tradingview.

Comment: I think this setting is all or nothing, and it can't be disabled for a specific website or websites. You may just have to disable it before you visit these trading sites. Alternatively, you could create a second user with the setting disabled, and visit these sites exclusively through that user. This comment assumes you are using macOS, where you have the ability to create different users. If you are on iOS, this is not possible. Please edit your question/tags to indicate macOS, iOS or possibly both!